# Никак не могу сделать условие для спуска по дереву

Tags: алгоритм, c++11, бинарное-дерево

Здравствуте. Я делаю [эту](http://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?chapterid=752#1) задачу. В моём решении есть проблема: у меня не получается сделать условие для такого спуска по дереву, что-бы результат был оптимален. Это условие находится в процедуре find.

Помогите пожауйста написать это условие

Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

void preparationToCreateTree(int &n, int &posA);
void initTree(int &n, int &posA, int tree[], int numTree[], int &posZ);
void find(int &l, int &r, int tree[], int numTree[], int &posA, int &posZ, int &n, int &result, int level);

int main()
{
    int k;
    int posA = 1, posZ;
    int n;
    preparationToCreateTree(n, posA);
    int *numTree = new int[posA + n + 3 + 1];
    int *tree    = new int[n + 1 + 3];
    int l, r, result, level;
    initTree(n, posA, tree, numTree, posZ);

    int levelPoint, usedPoint;

    levelPoint = posA;
    usedPoint  = posZ + 1;
    while(levelPoint != 1)
    {
        for(int i = levelPoint; i < usedPoint; i+=2)
        {
            if( tree[numTree[i]] > tree[numTree[i + 1]])
                numTree[i / 2] = numTree[i];
            else
                numTree[i / 2] = numTree[i + 1];
        //    cout << i << endl;
        }
        usedPoint = levelPoint;
        levelPoint /= 2;
    }

    cin >> k;
    for(int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    {
        cin >> l >> r;
        result = -1;
        find(l, r, tree, numTree, posA, posZ, n, result, 1);
        cout << tree[numTree[result]] << " " << numTree[result] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


void preparationToCreateTree(int &n, int &posA)
{
    cin >> n;
    while(posA < n)
        posA *= 2;
}

void initTree(int &n, int &posA, int tree[], int numTree[] , int &posZ)
{
    //cout << "!!!";
    tree[0] = -1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        cin >> tree[i];

    for(int i = 1; i <= posA + n + 3 + 1; i++)
        numTree[i] = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        numTree[posA + i - 1] = i;

    if(n % 2 != 0)
        n++, numTree[posA + n - 1] = 0, tree[n] = -1;
    if((n / 2) % 2 != 0)
        n += 2, numTree[posA + n - 1] = 0, numTree[posA + n - 2] = 0, tree[n] = -1, tree[n - 1] = -1;

    posZ = posA + n - 1;
}

void find(int &l, int &r, int tree[], int numTree[], int &posA, int &posZ, int &n, int &result, int level)
{
    if (numTree[level] == 0)
            return;
    if( (numTree[level] >= l) && (numTree[level] <= r) && result == -1 )
        result = level;
    else{
        if(  ) //Вот тут не могу придумать условие
            find(l, r, tree, numTree, posA, posZ, n, result, level * 2);
        else
            find(l, r, tree, numTree, posA, posZ, n, result, level * 2 + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: В принципе у м еня проблема только с одной процедурой. На весь остальной код можно не обращать внимание

Comment: В таком случае, "Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для её воспроизведения** прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей."

Comment: Я явно указал всё. Он не находит ответ, что логично, означает что переменные не меняют своё значение. Это самый минимальный код для отлова ошибки. Без одной процедуры другая откажется работать. Даже переменная не будет создаваться

Comment: Для разгона: чему равно `n` при создании `numTree` и `tree`?

Comment: Оно вводится вручную в preparatiinToCreateTree

Answer (score 0):

Я совсем не понял ход вашей мысли, какое и зачем дерево, для какого случая столько функций?
Всё банально просто:

```
int Array[K];

uint[2] Find(uint Start, End)
{
   uint[2] Result;
   uint Temp = 0;

   while(Start < End)
   {
      if(Array[Start] > Temp)
      {
        Temp = Array[Start];
      }
      Start++;
   }
   Result[0] = Temp;
   Result[1] = Start;
   return Result;
}
```

Это примерный код, под c++ сам подстраивай.
И осталось только методы-интерпретаторы добавить, главное не забудь что массив нумеруется с нуля.

Comment: Вы не задумывались о том, что в этой задаче нельзя обойтись без бинарных деревьев? Почитайте условия задачи, по которой я пишу программу. Там в массиве до 10^5 элементов и ещё столько-же запросов. Если всё делать в лоб, то при максимальном количестве самых неоптимальных запросов может накопиться целых 10^10 итераций. Он явно столько не сможет за 1.5 секунды. Тут сделать бинарное дерево, в которое закидать информацию о том, какие элементы больше и уже по нему находить ответ

Comment: @ЕгорЛевоненко а сколько времени уйдёт на сортировку?, да и 10^10 = 10 гигагерц, что вполне реально за 1.5-1.8с на 3 гц на двух ядрах процессоре

Comment: А где-то тут есть сортировка?)

Comment: @ЕгорЛевоненко я просто не могу понять использование вами дерева, это заместо структуры, где есть значение и порядок?

Comment: Деревья работают достаточно быстро для ограничений в задаче, в отличии от того решения "в лоб" которое просто проходит по всему отрезку и ищет.

Comment: @ЕгорЛевоненко а что хранится в дереве, какова структура?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47947/discussion-between---and---).